# JAVA - won't compile

Tags: java, compiler-errors

My driver class won't compile. It keeps saying that I'm giving the wrong types. I have declared the variables in the Phone class and then created information about the phone in the driver and want to store it in the array.

Phone class

```
public class Phone extends Technology {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String colour;
    private int inStock=10;
    private int sold;

    //Constructor
    public Phone (String itemsId,  String brand, double price, String name, String type, String colour ) {

        super(itemsId, brand, price );
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.colour = colour;
    }   
}
```

This is the part of the driver class that wont compile, I cant figure out what im doing wrong. I have created information about the phone in the same order that they are in the phone class.

```
// Creating 10 phones and storing in arrayList
public void pickPhone(){

    Phone phone = new Phone("A223","Apple", "€679.00 ", "iPhone 5s", "Smartphone ", " Black");
    phoneList.add(phone);

    phone = new Phone("A252","Apple", " €649.00 ", " iPhone 5s", "Smartphone ", " White");
    phoneList.add(phone);

    phone = new Phone("A264","Apple", " €329.00 ", " iPhone 4s", "Smartphone ", " Black");
    phoneList.add(phone);

    phone = new Phone("S586","Sony", " €570.00 ", " Xperia Z1", "Smartphone ", " Black");
    phoneList.add(phone);

    phone = new Phone("S549","Sony", " €260.00 ", " Xperia SP", "Smartphone ", " Black");
    phoneList.add(phone);

    phone = new Phone("G359","Samsung", " €530.00 ", "Galaxy S4", "Smartphone ", " Black");
    phoneList.add(phone);

    phone = new Phone("G375","Samsung", " €530.00 ", "Galaxy S4", "Smartphone ", "White");
    phoneList.add(phone);

    phone = new Phone("G352","Samsung", "  €350.00 ", "Galaxy S4 Mini", "Smartphone ", "White");
    phoneList.add(phone);

    phone = new Phone("H488"," HTC ", " €529.00 ", "One", "Smartphone ", "Black");
    phoneList.add(phone);

    phone = new Phone("H463"," HTC ", " €419.00 ", "One Mini ", "Smartphone ", "Silver");
    phoneList.add(phone);

}
```

Comment: can you tell us your compile error

Comment: You're passing `String`s for the `double price`.

Comment: The constructor is expecting a double (third param), you're passing a String instead.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  There's sufficient information to diagnose this.  They're passing String in place of `double`.

Comment: Perhaps your primary array should not be named the same as the class that holds it.  I can't imagine that working with no errors.

Comment: how is it a string ? i have a price

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I would not have closed as "lacks sufficient information" (it's all there), but certainly as "too localized."

Comment: @user3537296 You've put the value inside `"`s. You need to pass a `double` (numeric) value.

Comment: @user - " €419.00 " is a string.  Lose the money character and the quotes.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I don't see any array. Having a variable named `phone` is fine.

Comment: @Griffey - that's really interesting. I would never try that, as I would consider that to be dangerous. Also... I see what you mean.  It's a constructor.  My bad.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Java is case-sensitive, so Phone and phone are different. In this case `Phone` is a class and `phone` is a reference variable of type `Phone`, not an array. And right, he has a `Phone` constructor for his `Phone` class.

Comment: But his constructor is named Phone, and his class is named Phone. Initial cap. The variable he's populating later is named phone. That's what I don't get.

Comment: @durbnpoisn The constructor _must_ be named the same as the class, as it is here. The variable `phone` is not named the same as the class and therefore there is no conflict.

Comment: Oh.  Makes sense.  Please pardon my ignorance on this.  I've been doing Android Dev for only a few weeks myself.  So I'm still learning - thus why I asked the question.  Up to this point, I've yet to use a constuctor.  So I'd not run into this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor

```
public Phone (String itemsId,  String brand, double price, String name, String type, String colour )
```

`price` is a double, but you pass a string e.g. `" €419.00 "`

You would have to pass the price as e.g. `419.0` (no Euro sign, no spaces, no double-quotes around it).

```
Phone phone = new Phone("A223","Apple", 679.0, "iPhone 5s", "Smartphone ", " Black");
phoneList.add(phone);
```

Answer (score 1):

your mistake is for the price you ask for a double not a string in your constructor of phone

For example "€679.00" is a string. if you want a double you have to pass 679.00

you have to modify your constructor or to modify your argument

Comment: Oh ok then how should i write it ?

Comment: no i have found it but next time be more precise in your question I hope it helps mark as answered

Comment: If i want to pass an int is it the same thing ?

Comment: for an int you can't have cents precision your price will become 679. You can't do 679.50. If you want int a tip is to write price in cents and 679.50 double will become 67950 int. You have the choice